# what is the regex for the following part?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
src/insp/custom/extractThis1.q.ts
```

what would be the regex for extractThis1 ?

I have tried like this `/\/(.*).q.ts/gm` but didn't work

Comment: Are you looking for a regex solution only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match until the last occurrence of `/`, and then use a capture group to match any char except a `.` followed by `.q.ts`

```
^.*\/([^.]+)\.q\.ts$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/arurcj/1)

```js
const s = "src/insp/custom/extractThis1.q.ts";
const regex = /^.*\/([^.]+)\.q\.ts$/;
const m = s.match(regex);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```